Running a background task every 10 minutes to update server with device location
I am writing a flutter app (Android & IOS) which requires sending the device location once every ~10 minutes.
This task is required to continue running in the background even when the app is in the back or terminated.
The server uses the location to send a background notification to the app when the user is in proximity of another user of the app.
I know there are many limitations set by the OS on background tasks, and there is the impact of frequent location updates on battery life.
What is the best strategy of implementing such a requirement?
I have seen packages like workmanager & flutter_background_service - but it appears from their documents that the minimal interval is 15 minutes, and it is not guaranteed.
There are also packages for getting background location (such as background_location, or background-location-tracker). These are triggered by location changes and not by time interval and I am concerned they can be more battery draining if run over many hours a day.

You should implement an isolate with (or without) a package and in this isoate you implement a periodic timer that execute what you need every 10 minutes.

If I understood correctly that is what the background service packages do. According to the documentation when the app is in the background or terminated then the OS will override the requested interval of execution (The isolate will not get execution time) and at best it will be once every 15 minutes.
